# How to convert 25 to 01 at the begining of Time in Python Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have in Data Frame column Time, but I have for example time: 25:58:37, How can I change all values in this column which started from 25 to start from 01 ? So I need to change the first value of this column from 25 to 01 only if the first value is 25, how can I do that ?
[image]

I can add that this column is "object" type and it is impossible to convert it to datetime because of:

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

So at the begining I need to change 25 to 01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably makes more sense to use `Timedelta` instead of `Datetime` type:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

If you insist on changing `25` to `01`, you can try:

```
df['Time'].str.replace('^25', '01')
```